# Disable Case Sensitivity for Queries in ArcGIS Server 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am searching a field on a layer in ArcGIS Server 10 with wildcards.

The query will be something similar to "STREETNAME like '%MAIN%'"

Right now the searches are case sensitive, so it will only return results with MAIN in the STREETNAME field as opposed to Main.

Is it possible for me to disable case sensitive searching?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: what is your data store?  i'm on sql server 2008 and like statements are case insensitive, so STREET_NAME LIKE '%MaNgO%' and STREET_NAME LIKE '%MANGO%' return the same results.

Comment: File GeoDatabase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a SQL function to modify the value before making the comparison. Example:

```
upper(STREETNAME) like '%MAIN%'
```

The SQL function may vary from the example depending on the datasource (file GDB, SDE, etc).